# How do I accept an int in xml and serialize it as an enum

Tags: c#, xml, enums, xml-serialization

I am working on an API that accepts XML in the request body.

When I receive the XML, I use the `XmlSerializer` class to convert the XML to an object. One of the properties of that object is a list of enum values.

What I would like to do is make it so that the client can pass the int value of the enum rather than having to pass in the name of the value.

For example, lets say part of the xml looks like this:

```
<Amenities>
    <AmenityCode>1</AmenityCode>
    <AmenityCode>2</AmenityCode>
</Amenities>
```

And I have an my class is defined like this

```
public class HotelSearch{
  public List<AmenityCode> Amenities { get; set; }
}

public enum AmenityCode {
   AirConditioning = 1,
   AirportTranfer = 2
}
```

Is there a way to tell the `XmlSerializer` to accept `<AmenityCode>1</AmenityCode>` and translate it to `AmenityCode.AirConditioning` when I serialized a `HotelSearch` object?

I know I can just create a new `HotelSearch` object and set all of the properties by parsing through the XML, but my overall goal is laziness and that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Probably not, one wonders why you want to do this anyways. These XML files should be generated by programs with access to the enum names, not by hand.

Comment: The consumers of this service can be using any language so they need to be able to construct the raw xml. The best we can do is put enum types in our Xml Schema that they have to conform to (unless there is a better way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is recommended to have string values for enums in serialized/deserialized requests. but if you want an int value, then try using the XmlEnum attribute on the enums.

```
public enum AmenityCode 
{
       [XmlEnum("1")]
       AirConditioning = 1,
       [XmlEnum("2")]
       AirportTranfer = 2
}
```

there is also a way to create shimmed properties, but that gets too messy when many properties are involved.

Comment: I had tried something similar to that before but apparently I did a crappy job. Using XmlEnum worked nicely, thanks!